# vue and webpack problem when trying to run npm i

Tags: vue.js, npm, webpack, vuejs2, webpack-dev-server

i have this problem when i am trying to run npm install, the project was built with vuejs

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: mobadarat-admin-panel@1.0.0
npm ERR! Found: webpack@4.46.0
npm ERR! node_modules/webpack
npm ERR!   dev webpack@"^4.15.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer webpack@"^5.0.0" from mini-css-extract-plugin@2.6.1
npm ERR! node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin
npm ERR!   dev mini-css-extract-plugin@"^2.2.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
npm install --legacy-peer-deps
```

[Have a look at](https://blog.npmjs.org/post/626173315965468672/npm-v7-series-beta-release-and-semver-major)

Or

```
npm install --force
```